# Programmatically set binding order of a network adapter

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking

Is it possible to set the binding order of a network adapter to primary (topmost) if it's MAC address is within a predefined list by means of a batch file?

The list of valid MAC addresses may be specified as follows:

```
set myList=12-34-AB-0C-D5-67 00-1A-23-BC-45-D6 ...
```

I have googled for a while now but found nothing useful.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The priority of a network connection can be changed to the top of the binding order with the *nvspbind* tool. Refer to this site for some documentation about the tool: https://ss64.com/nt/nvspbind.html

There also seems to be a related superuser question available here: https://superuser.com/questions/983310/how-to-set-network-connection-priority-order-under-windows-with-wmic-or-vb-scrip

One possible way to associate physical addresses with network connection names would be to use the output of the **getmac /fo list /v** command.

Comment: Thank you for your help!